# C# process and analyse massive amounts of data before insert to sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, memory, bulkinsert

I need to write a c# application that monitors different packets (in xml format) received over a network.

There can be tens of thousands of packets received per minute and each need to be inspected to determine appropriate action.

The application will monitor worker movement and actions in a building.

The packets are similar to the below :

`Movement` packets:

```
<packet>
   <datetime>12:01:25</datetime>
   <usertag>ABC</usertag>
   <movedir>IN</movedir>    
   <location>90</location>
   ...
</packet>
```

`Action` packets:

```
<packet>
    <datetime>12:07:45</datetime>
    <usertag>ABC</usertag>
    <actionid>1</movedir>
    .....
</packet>
```

The application needs to:

- Perform prefiltering to ensure only required packets are processed (no duplicate/irrelevant packets are processed)
- Record all User Movements (in time/out time/user/location)
- Record all actions and location where the action occurred (not part of the "action" packet needs to be determined from current location)
- Additional processing when user leaves a location to ensure they carried out correct sequence of jobs ("actions") in that location and record this information

All information needs to be recorded in the SQL Server database for reporting.

My dilemma is how best to achieve the above in the most efficient way possible.

As there will be massive amounts of data to process and write to SQL my plan is to "Queue" inserts and Bulk insert (BulkCopy) every X seconds.

My thoughts...

- User Thread 1 to read all the packets (should I read to memory ie `List<Packet>` or write to DAT file?)
- Main Thread processes iterates collection above

  - Determine if movement or action packet
  - If Movement add to `List<Movement>`

    For each of these I need to do a lookup on a database table to map location code to ID (should I bulk read this Location list into a dictionary once and refresh every X seconds?)
  - If action add to `List<Action>`
    For each of these i need to do a lookup on a database table / memory object (above) to see what location user is in currently to record this
  - When Out Movement Complete get list of actions carried out and apply rules (held in db) to ensure all work carried out
  - Every X Seconds Bulk Insert and refresh lists

I'm worried about the amount of information I will be holding in memory through out this process as its quite large. Anyone have any recommendations on how I might achieve this more efficiently? I want to keep the business logic in the code and not on server.

Many thanks!
Tom

Comment: Is Each of your packet i.e. movement or action packet carries a unique id with them and this id's are stored to database? And Is your database going to be updated from any other program, or your program is only making modification.

Comment: No there are no unique IDs sent in the packet.
The database may be updated by admins to add new users, locations etc. Also there will need to be a reporting front end which will need to access the data and results captured

Comment: Try using Parallel.ForEach for using more threads to process the data.

Comment: @Tom have you considered looking at SQL Server StreamInsight complex event processing to do this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sqlserver/ee476990.aspx

Comment: Sounds an awful lot premature optimisation to me 

10's of thousands a minute is not a lot, have you tried writing the application in its simplest form, what is the slowest section.